# How to make a checklist on Messenger bot get started page?

Tags: facebook, messenger

I see on the Fox News messenger bot that they have a checklist and a Follow button when you first open the bot.

I'm trying to do the same but can't find any reference to this in the messenger platform docs. All I can find is how to make a getting started button which does not allow for any options like a checklist.

Is this a publicly available feature?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v0EC.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is a plug in for the messenger bot and it's new. Here is the facebook wiki on it. You may have to update your javascript sdk to make it work.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/checkbox-plugin

Comment: Sorry, no that's not it. See the example picture for what I'm looking for